# How to get My Account number from a String using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string containing one bank account number.But i want to get that number only using javascript.How do it?

JS:

```
var string = "My Account number 1212125678 Avaliable $1,500";
var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

alert(numbers);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2xrqv/1786/

Comment: `alert(numbers[0])` http://jsfiddle.net/2xrqv/1788/

Comment: `Number(string.match(/number (\d+)/)[1])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you to get the number and text before the number:

```js
var string = "My Account number 1212125678 Avaliable $1,500";

var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

console.log(numbers[0]);
var text = string.split(numbers[0])[0];
console.log(text);
```

Comment: How to get string before number ?

Comment: You mean to get text `My Account number`? @snkranya

Comment: Yes..how to get it?